# opengl + emscripten textures not getting displayed

Tags: c++, opengl-es, emscripten

i am tring to display textures using opengles + emscripten, but all i am getting are black triangles.

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Zgg.png)

my vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 position;    
attribute vec4 color;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 uv;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec2 v_uv;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

highp mat4 transpose(in highp mat4 inMatrix) {
    highp vec4 i0 = inMatrix[0];
    highp vec4 i1 = inMatrix[1];
    highp vec4 i2 = inMatrix[2];
    highp vec4 i3 = inMatrix[3];

    highp mat4 outMatrix = mat4(
                 vec4(i0.x, i1.x, i2.x, i3.x),
                 vec4(i0.y, i1.y, i2.y, i3.y),
                 vec4(i0.z, i1.z, i2.z, i3.z),
                 vec4(i0.w, i1.w, i2.w, i3.w)
                 );

    return outMatrix;
}

void main()                  
{  
   v_color = color;
   v_normal = normal;
   v_uv = uv;
                             
   gl_Position = projection * view * transpose(model) * vec4(position.xyz, 1.0);  
}
```

fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec3 v_normal;
varying vec2 v_uv;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()                                  
{                                            
  // gl_FragColor = v_color;              
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, v_uv.xy);              
}
```

texture create function:

```
void IG::Texture::create(unsigned char* image, 
                                    uint32_t width, 
                                    uint32_t height, 
                                    uint32_t channels)
{
    if(image == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout<<"Texture creation failed! invalid image data.."<<std::endl;
        return;
    }
    

    glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );
    glGenTextures(1, &ID);
    
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ID);
    // set the texture wrapping parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, attribs.uv_mode);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, attribs.uv_mode);
    // set texture filtering parameters
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, attribs.min_filter);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, attribs.mag_filter);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                    attribs.mip_level,
                    GL_RGB,
                    width,
                    height,
                    attribs.border,
                    GL_RGB, 
                    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                    image);

    // glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

here attribs is a struct with values:

```
uv_mode(GL_REPEAT),
min_filter(GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR),
mag_filter(GL_LINEAR),
mip_level(0),
border(0)
```

i have verified that the image is valid using stb_image.

inside the draw loop all triangles are iterated and drawn using this call:

```
void Renderer::draw_objects(){
    for(auto& v : gl_objects){
        auto &shape = v.second;

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, shape.tex.ID);

        shader->set_mat4("model", shape.transform);        
        glBindVertexArray(shape.VAO);

        glUniform1i(shape.tex.samplerLoc, 0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    }
}
```

i am taking references from these links [learopengl](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Textures) [emscripten opengles examples](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/main/tests/third_party/glbook/Chapter_9/Simple_Texture2D/Simple_Texture2D.c)

i am unable to debug what i am doing wrong here. what could be the issue here?

Comment: probably not related, but at the end of your texture creation method, you should add `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);` to ensure the texture is not modified in a subsequent part of the code. Are you sure your properly get the uniform location of your texture sampler ?

Comment: I am also wondering if this is not a mipmap related problem, why do you commented `glGenerateMipmap` ?

Comment: @Sedenion yes the uniform location i am getting is a non-negative integer, i varified it by logging it, and i commented out `glGenerateMipmap` as it was complaing that the image was not a power of 2, i thought maybe i could be the issue

Comment: @Sedenion i tried adding glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0) at the end, the issue remains

Comment: I am now pretty sure that your problem come from the missing mipmaps, it try to render a specific mipmaps that is not created, resulting in black pixels. Indeed some versions of OpenGL ES have limitations about mipmap generation. Try to create a texture with the proper power-of-2 resolution and call `glGenerateMipmap`.

Comment: @Sedenion, **it worked** i used a 512x512 image and used `glGenerateMipmap`, and it worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem come from the missing mipmaps, it try to render a specific mipmaps that is not created, resulting in black pixels.

A proper call to `glGenerateMipmap` after `glTexImage2D` would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't generate mipmaps [mipmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) (with [`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml)) you must use one of the non mipmap minifying functions (`GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR`). If you use a mipmap minification function, the texture would be "Mipmap Incomplete".
Eiter use `min_filter(GL_LINEAR)` or call `glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`.